# Auto fill sql table based on entries in two different tables

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have two tables (lets call them table A and B) both of them contain data about shops. Table A contains data about Shop name, address, and phonenumber and table b contains data about shops opening and closing times, location coordinates, logo etc. I use a third party application which fills the data into table A and B. Now I want to create a new table(table C) and have all the required columns in that table. Is there something I can do so that each time a entry is made to table A and B, the data is also added to table C? If yes how should I do it? (I cannot modify the third party application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a perfect job for a [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html) in the database.

Answer (score 1):

Triggers aren't great in MySQL, but if you only need read-only access to that data, you can create a view to get that.  Be warned though, views in MySQL aren't great either if you join against them.

something like:

```
create view shop_all_v as
  select 
    a.shop_name, a.address, a.phone_number, b.opening_time, b.closing_time
  from table_a a, table_b b
  where a.shop_id = b.shop_id;
```

The other way is to create a scheduled job that updates the table in application code.  Not the best thing either, but with MySQL you're a bit stuck.  You can create timestamp columns that will help keep track of when a sync occurred.  This isn't all that crazy as it's standard practice for aggregate data processing, just not recommended when you need realtime reliability.